# How to create an ICollection with TModel?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, icollection

So I have a class called Repository which holds this method:

```
public IEnumerable<TModel> UpdateOrCreate<TModel>(ICollection<TModel> itemsToUpdate)
        where TModel : EndpointModelBase
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

How can I call this method with the correct parameter?
My trouble comes with trying to make an ICollection for the parameter to pass in?

Comment: Maybe you can share the code where you run into a compiler error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `List<EndpointModelBase>` since it implements `ICollection<T>`.

```
List<EndpointModelBase> itemsToUpdate = new List<EndpointModelBase>();
UpdateOrCreate<EndpointModelBase>(itemsToUpdate);
```

Comment: That has solved my problem, thanks a lot. 
I didnt really understand the EndpointModelBase which was catching me out :)